# How to validate clients certificate from opcua server using node library

Tags: node.js, openssl, x509certificate, opc-ua, node-opcua

Im creating a opcua server using node-opcua. The user validation by user and password works, but now im trying to add certificates and i dont get how to do it.

I understand the server has its own certificate and privatekey, and each client has its own certificates. Also i know that the clients need to know the server's certificate, but i dont know how the server can identify each client through the sended certificate, where the server saves it.

I created server certificates:

```
    const serverCertificateManager = new OPCUACertificateManager({
        automaticallyAcceptUnknownCertificate: true,
        name: "PKI",
        rootFolder: "./certificates/server/PKI",
        keySize: 2048
    })
    await serverCertificateManager.initialize()

    if (!fs.existsSync(certificateFile)) {

        console.log("Creating self-signed certificate");
    
        await serverCertificateManager.createSelfSignedCertificate({
          applicationUri: `urn:${hostname}:NodeOPCUA-Server`,
          dns: hostname ? [hostname, fqdn] : [fqdn],
          outputFile: certificateFile,
          subject: "/CN=Sterfive/DC=Test",
          startDate: new Date(),
          validity: 365 * 10
        })
      }
```

and from the server i created user certificates:

```
    const userCertificateManager = new OPCUACertificateManager({
        automaticallyAcceptUnknownCertificate: false,
        name: "UserPki",
        rootFolder: "./certificates/clients/PKI",
        keySize: 2048
    })
    await userCertificateManager.initialize()
```

That creates in the `certificates` folder, a `clients` and a `server` folder, each one with issuers, own, rejected and trusted.
In the path `server/PKI/certs/` the certificate and the private key are created by running the above managers. And in `clients`there are created some certificates in trusted, and when i connect a client without any certificate (just with user-password), another trust certificate is created with its session name.

Next, i created the server:

```
    const server = new OPCUAServer({
        port: port,
        serverInfo: {
            applicationName: { text: "Enterprise", locale: "en" },
            applicationUri: `urn:${hostname}:NodeOPCUA-Server`,
            productUri: "NodeOPCUA-Server"
        },
        buildInfo: {
            productName: "Enterprise",
            buildNumber: "1002",
            buildDate: new Date(),
        },
        userManager: {

            isValidUserAsync: function (userName: string, password: string, callback: Callback<boolean>) {
                setImmediate(function () {
                    const authorized = clientsData.some((client:Client )=> client.username === userName && client.password === password)
                    callback(null, authorized);
                })
            },

            getUserRoles: function (user: string): NodeId[] {
                return [makeNodeId(user, 1)];
            }

        },
        serverCertificateManager,
        userCertificateManager,
        certificateFile: certificateFile,
        privateKeyFile: privateKeyFile,
        securityPolicies: [SecurityPolicy.Basic256Sha256],
        securityModes: [MessageSecurityMode.Sign],
        serverCapabilities: {
            maxSessions: 10,
            maxSubscriptionsPerSession: 10,
            maxMonitoredItemsPerSubscription: 30,
            operationLimits: {
                maxNodesPerRead: 10,
                maxNodesPerMethodCall: 10
            }
        },
        maxConnectionsPerEndpoint: 10,
        hostname: hostname,
        allowAnonymous: false
    })
```

This is my server code, but when I try to connect a client using the same library, the process fails. The client has this code:

```
const client = OPCUAClient.create({
    clientName: username,
    applicationName: username,
    connectionStrategy: connectionStrategy,
    securityMode: MessageSecurityMode.Sign,
    securityPolicy: SecurityPolicy.Basic256Sha256,
    endpointMustExist: true,
    serverCertificate: serverCertificateBuffer,
    certificateFile: certificateFile,
    privateKeyFile: privateKeyFile
});

const session = await client.createSession({
    type: UserTokenType.Certificate,
            certificateData: fs.readFileSync(certificateFile),
            privateKey: fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFile, 'utf-8')
    })
```

Where the server certificate is the created in the `server` folder, the privatekey is the created
by the server manager in the `clients` folder and the `certificate` is created by using the OPCUACertificateManager. When i try to connect to server, client throw this error: `Error: The connection may have been rejected by server`.

I suspect that the certificate implementation is not working because im missing something. Im really new in opcua.
Some one know how to correctly implementate the certificate comunication? also i need to create a certificate per user, so i can verify and recognized every user to track the clients activity.

I hope ur help, im stuck

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your client public certificate (.der) into the trust folder of your server.

This should be either server\PKI\trusted or server\PKI\trusted\certs

Comment: Thanks, I finally solved this by connecting through UA expert App. And with the certificates created by a node-opcua client when i add some clientCertificateManager and serverCertificate. This clients used the private key created for the users by the server when i setted userCertificateManager. I tried to create an client certificate by using this private key and ssl commands in the terminal, but i didnot get a good certificate, the server doesnt recognize it.
But when a server doesnt allow the connection from a previous trusted client, i simply moved it from rejected to trusted and it works.